# struct assignment operator on arrays

Tags: arrays, struct, assignment-operator

Suppose I defined a structure like this:

```
struct person
{
    char name [10];
    int  age;
};
```

and declared two person variables:

```
person Bob;
person John;
```

where Bob.name = "Bob", Bob.age = 30 and John.name = "John",John.age = 25. and I called

```
Bob = John;
```

struct person would do a [Memberwise assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0c54csc%28VS.80%29.aspx) and assign Johns's member values to Bob's.

But arrays can't assign to arrays, so how does the assignment of the "name" array work?

Answer (score 1):

When the C language was first thrown together, it was not intended to become a mighty force which would still be in use decades later.  It was intended to be something that would quickly and easily fulfill some immediate needs, but it was pretty horrid.  Many of the features one takes for granted, such as the ability to pass structures by value or (if I recall) even assign them directly did not exist.  The decomposition of arrays to pointers, however, was part of the language from the beginning.

When structures became more powerful in later versions of the language, there was no problem allowing the notation `struct1 = struct2;` to represent a copy from `struct2` to `struct1`, since such an expression didn't have any meaning prior to that.  On the other hand, array types had their own pre-existing rules, and there would have been no way to allow array assignment to work like struct assignment without breaking the dozens of programs that had been written for the fledgeling language.

Consequently, copying a struct which contains an array will work the way one would have expected that copying an array would work, because the decomposition of an array to a pointer only happens when the array is accessed "by name".  If a struct contains `unsigned char byteArray[64];`, from the struct's perspective that's simply a blob of 64 bytes.  If one refers to `theStruct.byteArray`, that reference will decompose into a pointer the way an array-variable reference would, but when assigning `theStruct` to another variable of the same type, the compiler ignores the internals.